# NVidia driver 320.86 texture buffer bug leads to crash

Tags: c++, opengl

The following code crashes really quickly ( way before the max buffer size of 2^27 texels )

I stripped every useless line of code, to make it easier to read.

```
const int MAX_LAYER_DEPTH = 5;

#include "vapp.h"

#include "vmath.h"

#include <stdio.h>

BEGIN_APP_DECLARATION(OITDemo)
    // Override functions from base class
   virtual void Initialize(const char * title);
    virtual void Display(bool auto_redraw);
    virtual void Finalize(void);
    virtual void Reshape(int width, int height);

    GLuint  linked_list_buffer;
    GLuint  linked_list_texture;
    GLint current_width;
    GLint current_height;
END_APP_DECLARATION()

DEFINE_APP(OITDemo, "Order Independent Transparency")

void OITDemo::Initialize(const char * title)
{
    base::Initialize(title);
    glGenBuffers(1, &linked_list_buffer);
    glGenTextures(1, &linked_list_texture);
    Reshape(100,100);
    return;
}

void OITDemo::Display(bool auto_redraw)
{

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBindImageTexture(1, linked_list_texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32UI);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    base::Display();

    return;
}

void OITDemo::Reshape(int width, int height)
{
    current_width = width;
    current_height = height;

    glBindImageTexture(1, 0, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32UI);
    static GLuint texBufferSize = 2047;
    ++texBufferSize;
    printf("%d : texBufferSize\n",texBufferSize);
    glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, linked_list_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, texBufferSize * texBufferSize * MAX_LAYER_DEPTH * sizeof(vmath::vec4), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);

    // Bind it to a texture (for use as a TBO)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, linked_list_texture);
    glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32UI, linked_list_buffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);

    glViewport(0, 0, current_width, current_height);
    return;
}

void OITDemo::Finalize(void)
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &linked_list_texture);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &linked_list_buffer);
}
```

The driver most probably can't handle fragmentation
It crashes between reallocation of 21694445 ( 2083 x 2083 x 5 ) and 23587920 elements. The maximum buffer size ( number of texels ) returned by the graphic card is 2^27 ( 134 millions texels )

It seems to work better if we allocate one big buffer at the start of the application and never change it. 
But fails miserably if we try to reallocate it during the life of the application.

Originally the code binds the image texture then trace using a shader that uses that image texture with imageStore but I discovered that I don't need any shader to make the driver crash.

Any clue to predict/prevent the driver crash?

Comment: Is your platform 32 bit or 64 bit. I agree that this could be an address space fragmentation problem. If you're working on a 32 bit system we can rule out process address space fragmentation to be the reason. /// Also I suggest you omit that `glBindImageTexture` call from your code; it's prone for causing confusion in the unwary reader (I was scratching my head over it, until I understood why it's there, but it adds nothing to understand the problem).

Comment: In fact the glBindImageTexture causes the problem. The original code binds a shader that uses the image to store accumulated fragments but I discovered I could make the driver crash even without the shader. If I don't bind my image texture, my guess is that the driver optimizes it out. I'm on a 64 bit windows 7 with 24 gigs installed RAM. My graphic cars has 1 Gig.

Comment: Anyway I think we agree this could be a space fragmentation problem. Do you know of a way to prevent/predict that ? Thank you for your answer btw.

Comment: If you want other people to be notified you have replied to their comments, you have to add @[username] to the beginning of your comment. Thought you might want to know. (Ex. @datenwolf)

Comment: @datenwolf I know, I was telling that to the OP :P

Comment: I'm in contact with NVidia developers, they filed it as a bug report. I'll post the fix if they ever make one.

Comment: It seems that NVidia fixed the problem. I cannot make it crash anymore.